# JPA2 Criteria API: What is the difference between using Entity.class and the EntityType of the Metamodel in the from clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

What is the differenc between:

```
Root<Person> person = cq.from(Person.class);
```

and

```
EntityType<Person> Person_ = em.getMetamodel().entity(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = cq.from(Person_);
```

I have seen both in several tutorials..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

Looking at Hibernate's [CriteriaQuery parent's QueryStructure from(..)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.5.2-Final/org/hibernate/ejb/criteria/QueryStructure.java#QueryStructure.from%28javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType%29) methods:

```
public <X> Root<X> from(Class<X> entityClass) {
    EntityType<X> entityType = criteriaBuilder.getEntityManagerFactory()
            .getMetamodel()
            .entity( entityClass );
    if ( entityType == null ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( entityClass + " is not an entity" );
    }
    return from( entityType );
}

public <X> Root<X> from(EntityType<X> entityType) {
    RootImpl<X> root = new RootImpl<X>( criteriaBuilder, entityType );
    roots.add( root );
    return root;
}
```

We see, that one of them is just an overloading.

## Outcome

More convenient and boiler-plate-escaping way would be passing Class as the parameter.

## Advice

You did not provide which JPA implementation you are using, since JPA's CriteriaQuery is just an interface, while implementation provider such as EclipseLink or Hibernate provide actual implementation. Next time it would be greate if you take that into consideration.

Comment: Im using Hibernate as implementation. Thanks for your answer :)